# How to Access package private Class from a Class in some other package?

Tags: java, access-specifier

I have following classses

*Hello.java*

```
package speak.hello;

import java.util.Map;

import speak.hi.CustomMap;
import speak.hi.Hi;

public class Hello {

    private Hi hi;

    Hello(Hi hi) {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public String sayHi() {
        return hi.sayHi();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return hi.getMap();
    }

    public void clearMap() {
        hi.getMap().clear();
    }

    public void discardMap() {
        CustomMap map = (CustomMap) hi.getMap();
        map.discard();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hello = new Hello(new Hi());
        System.out.println(hello.sayHello());
        System.out.println(hello.sayHi());
        System.out.println(hello.getMap());
        hello.clearMap();
        System.out.println("--");
        hello.discardMap();
    }

}
```

*Hi.java*

```
package speak.hi;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Hi {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return new CustomMap<String, Object>();
    }
}
```

*CustomMap.java*

```
package speak.hi;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class CustomMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7979398843650044928L;

    public void discard() {
        System.out.println("Discarding Map");
        this.clearCache();
        this.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("Clearing Map");
        super.clear();
    }

    private void clearCache() {
        System.out.println("Clearing Map");
    }
}
```

This works fine until I remove `public` access specifier from `CustomMap`

```
package speak.hi;

import java.util.HashMap;

class CustomMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7979398843650044928L;

    public void discard() {
        System.out.println("Discarding Map");
        this.clearCache();
        this.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("Clearing Map");
        super.clear();
    }

    private void clearCache() {
        System.out.println("Clearing Map");
    }
}
```

Compiler yells that

> The type speak.hi.CustomMap is not *visible*

Now If I don't have options to modify `speak.hi.CustomMap` (third party jar etc..) Is there any way I could still use `CustomMap` from `speak.hello.Hello`?

---

One option that I know is to move `speak.hello.Hello` to `speak.hi.Hello` as Now Hello is in package `speak.hi` it can access package private Class `Hi`

---

Is there any other way to do this ? Using reflection perhaps ?

---

**EDIT** :Updated with additional details as requested by @StephenC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following method Invokes `default` scoped class method using reflection

```
public void discardMap() {
    //CustomMap map = (CustomMap) hi.getMap();
    //map.discard();
    try {
        Object o =hi.getClass().getMethod("getMap").invoke(hi);
        Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("discard");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous advice. Fix the access modifier in the class.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any other way to do this ? Using reflection perhaps ?

Yes.  Reflection can be used to bypass the Java access rules, if your application has full privilege.

For instance, to access a `private` field of an object from a different class, you need to:

- Get the object's `Class` object.
- Use the `Class.getDeclaredField(...)` method to get a `Field` object for the field.
- Call `Field.setAccessible(true)` to turn off the access check.
- Call `Class.getField(object, Field)` to get the field's value (or boxed value if it is a primitive type).

If the class itself is not accessible, you need to make sure that you don't refer to the classes identifier in your source code ... 'cos that will result in a compilation error.  Instead, assign its reference to (say) variable of type `Object` or of some other visible supertype, and perform more specific operations on the instance reflectively.

---

As you might imagine, this is tedious and error prone.  You'd be advised to find a better way, like:

- getting the suppliers of the classes to fix whatever is causing you to need to break the visibility restrictions,
- getting the suppliers of the classes to change their visibility,
- finding another way to use the classes that doesn't require breaking open their abstraction, or
- ditching them and finding (or writing) something better.

(Generally speaking, if you have to break open an abstraction then  something is wrong with either the abstraction itself or the way you are using it.)

---

Finally, I should add that untrusted code is (should be) run in a security sandbox that blocks the use of the key reflective operations.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be possible because:

Class  :

Accessible to class from same package?

- public : yes
- protected : yes
- default : yes
- private : no

Accessible to class from different package?

- public : yes
- protected : no
- default : unless it is a subclass
- private : no

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to use non-API classes as they might change in any future version and can break your code.

How did you find out about this class? Is it an Open Source library?

Try to contact the authors of the library, tell them your use case and find a way with them to offer a public API. If it's an open source library you could help them by providing a patch.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this solution for sake of completeness.

One option that I know is to move speak.hello.Hello to speak.hi.Hello as Now Hello is in package speak.hi it can access package private Class Hi

```
package speak.hi;

public class Hello {

    private Hi hi;

    Hello(Hi hi) {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public String sayHi() {
        return hi.sayHi();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hello = new Hello(new Hi());
        System.out.println(hello.sayHello());
        System.out.println(hello.sayHi());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The security model is this : a model to provide security :) If you designed class Hi and delivered it to customers with private access, you wouldn't like them to be able to bypass your restrictions, would you?

Comment: In general No , But you know Frameworks are designed by humans, and humans make mistake ! so when I need to use such framework I am forced to find a hack :)

Comment: The Java access modifiers are NOT primarily about security.  They are about maintaining abstraction boundaries.  (Hint: if you know what you are doing, you can use reflection to look at and change things that the access rules say you can't.)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if the authors of a library did not make a particular class part of the public API, it is because they don't want other people using it.  You should respect the decision even though you can break it using reflection.  Using private API is simply bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

1st class is in package a.b.c.class1 but class1 is private as well as abstract
2nd class is in package a.b.c.class2 extends class1 but class2 is public

3rd class is in package x.y.z.class3

So as to access class1 in class 3 you can write something like:-

Class baseClass = (new class2()).getClass();
and use the instance of its superclass then use:-
 baseClass.getSuperClass();
and use it wherever you want.

But then again the baseclass was made abstract and private for a reason hence not advisable to do so but then again this solution could be used as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I think by default the class will be **"default"** (package private, you can say), NOT "private". So it can be accessed with in the same package.

Moreover, you **CANNOT** make any *top level class Private in Java.

And if you want make a class default and still be able to access it in other package then what will be the purpose of having access specifiers (modifiers) ??

you either need to make class public or move to the same package.

Comment: -1: the default is "package private" and you can declare private (nested) classes.

Comment: but i think, here we are not talking about private (nested) classes.

Comment: Your statement says: "any class private in Java"

Comment: Just to confirm I meant "package private" = "default"  top level Class.

Comment: yea i got it.. (a little late)

Answer (score -2):

Not Possible you can not create your Hi class as private.

Comment: there are no private classes in java. if you try to make a class Private, it will give you compile time error "modifier private not allowed here"

Comment: That's only true for top-level classes.